# How to save a class object with a Drake plant object inside?

Tags: pickle, drake

`pickle.dump(pendulum, open("obj/pendulum1.obj", "wb"))` returns `TypeError: cannot pickle 'pydrake.examples.pendulum.PendulumPlant' object`. Here, `pendulum` is an object of a self-defined class with an PendulumPlant object inside.

Is it because pydrake is not natively written in python?

Answer (score 3):

Correct.  Most of the C++-backed classes in pydrake are not pickle-able

Some of the elementary pydrake classes *are* pickable though, such RigidTransform, RotationMatrix, etc. (See https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/11976.)

We could add pickling for *some* kinds of additional classes, but pickling a System or a Diagram is likely to be too difficult.

To save + restore a System like the pendulum, I'd say that re-creating the plant from scratch should be good -- it has no internal state so any one instance is the same as any other instance.

Comment: To add to this, one reason we don't support pickling things like like Systems or Diagrams in C++ is because we don't support serialization in general. If serialization were to be supported in C++, adding `pydrake` support (esp. in light of pickling) would be (nigh) trivial. However, serialization in general is a bit open-ended and non-trivial to implement, so recreating from scratch may be the better route.

Comment: FTR Here is an example of doing custom pickling for objects that are not picklable (if you want to try it yourself): https://gist.github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/677cac69889a32326b91be1d233aa8c2#file-pydrake_custom_pickling_example-py. Additionally, here's another (smaller) PR that adds pickling to `CameraInfo`: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/12131/files